# Geodan's Dual List Box: populating 'selected' box with different JSON file (PHP).

Tags: php, json, html

The goal is a subscription page where users can select properties to subscribe to. This works.

What I have: I'm using Geodan's [plugin](https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox) for being able to select items from the left list box (unselected) and moving them over to the right list box (selected). The left list box is populated via JSON, like so:

`<div class="form-group">
    <label for="properties">Properties</label>
    <div id="dual-list-box" class="form-group row">
        <select class="filter" name="dropdown[]" multiple="multiple" data title="Properties" 
        data-source="properties.json" data-value="index" data-text="name"></select>
    </div>
</div>`

Then you call this like so:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.filter').DualListBox();
});`

This works just fine. You can move properties from properties.json over to the right list box.

**What I want to achieve:**

Even though this initial subscription page works this fine, **say a user wants to edit their subscription**. Maybe they initially subscribed to ten properties, but now they want to add ten more. What you would want is:

-a separate page with the left list box being populated with properties.json

-the right list box being populated with a separate JSON file generated via PHP (getting the JSON file is easy): ***but I'm not sure if this plugin even allows to populate the right list box from an external source.***

I emailed Geodan roughly a week ago but have not heard back.

Any help on what I'm trying to achieve is appreciated. I am also open to using other plugins, if that would be an easier route.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate separate JSON for the left and right listbox. You just need to add the "selected" attribute to the options you want on the right.

Example:

```
<select id="ItemIds" name="ItemIds" multiple="multiple" data-title="Items" data-horizontal="false" data-json="false">
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 2</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">Item 4</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#ItemIds').DualListBox();
    });
</script>
```

Reference https://github.com/Geodan/DualListBox/issues/5